# Why is number of neurons in hidden layers a power of two?

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

There is a statement in [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/In-deep-learning-what-are-the-default-setup-for-the-Convolution-layer):

```
Layer depth is usually a power of 2 because it is convenient for the GPU.
```

Also, in fully connected layers number of neurons in every hidden layer corresponds to a power of 2.

But, why is the power of 2 convenient for GPU? If I have everything for the power of 3, why would it be inconvenient for GPU? I thought one would use GPU in deep learning only because one can parallelize batches/or convolution computation.

Comment: Is your computer a binary computer or a ternary one?

Comment: How do I understand it? Each GPU will have 2 or 3 cores?

Comment: It's more basic than that: ultimately, data are represented on your computer in a unit like a [bit.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)  How many states do the bits of your computer have?  Two?  Three?  Ten?

Comment: Read the answer by Dmitriy Genzel in Quora for a similar question: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-tend-to-use-powers-of-2-when-specifying-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-layer-of-a-neural-net-and-for-the-size-of-mini-batches